# How to simplify this SQL code to find all data contain null in all row and columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains about 19 columns. I want to find all rows and columns that contains any null values to identify them. Below example of the result that I want.

| customer_id | transaction_dt | payment_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16789544 | 12/8/1678 | null |
| 16543332 | null | cash |
| 16543332 | 12/8/1678 | null |
| 16543332 | null | online transacation |

Here are the simple code that I write:

```
SELECT *
FROM
Customer_Details
WHERE
customer_id is null,
or transaction_dt is null, 
or payment_type is null,
.
.
.
or quantity is null,
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

This query is not the most optimal but it is dynamic. Just sort of depends on what approach you want to do:

```sql
;WITH xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi) 
SELECT * 
FROM   Customer_Details AS CD
WHERE (
    SELECT CD.* 
    FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, TYPE
  ).exist('/row/*/@xsi:nil') = 1
```

Or

```sql
DECLARE @cd nvarchar(512) = N'dbo.[Customer_Details]';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @cd
    + N' WHERE 1 = 0';

SELECT @sql += N' OR ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N' IS NULL'
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@cd)
    AND is_nullable = 1;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: `.exist('/row/*/@xsi:nil') = 1` would be more performant.

Comment: Ya not a bad idea

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Please up-vote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: @lily, if the proposed solution is working for you, please don't forget to mark it as Answer

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky still looking for another answer..

Comment: XML/XQuery based method is working pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some trick, if you add any columns with **null** values it will yield to **null**.

```
SELECT *
FROM
Customer_Details
WHERE ISNULL(customer_id + transaction_dt + payment_type, '') = ''
```